# MPI.NET how to make processes send data in arbitrary order?

Tags: c#, mpi

I'm using `mpi.net`. I want that each processor(other than proc 0) to send data to process 0 in an arbitrary order. Here is a simplified piece of code:

```
            if (rank == 0)
            {
                int all = nTasks-1; //wich is the number of processes -1

                while (all > 0)
                {
                     Communicator.world.Receive<Pixelator>(Communicator.anySource, 1, out pixelus);
                     if (pixelus.x == -1)
                     {
                         all--;
                     }
                }
            }
            else
            {                    
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Communicator.world.Send<Pixelator>(some_data, 0, 1);
                }                    
                Communicator.world.Send<Pixelator>(-1, 0, 1);
            }
```

Problem is that process 0 receives all the information from another process at a time and then moves forward at receiving data from another process. For example, process 0 gets 
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 (these are the ranks of processes sending data). And i want it to be 1 5 2 3 1 1 4 3...or any arbitrary order... any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mpi.net specifically, but the code you posted should allow for any order. Are you running all processes on the same machine perhaps? If so, it could simply be that the scheduler completes each node's job in one go. Try putting a short (~1 sec) sleep inside the worker nodes' `for` loop.

Comment: while tryin' to get some sleep this idea popped into my head. But my program does some kind of image morphing and has to be fast. If i'm not going to find a better solution i'll do this cause i have to present the project for an exam tomorow...

Comment: The sleep would only serve to demonstrate that messages can be received in any order, it wouldn't need to be in the final code.

Comment: this solution was for better visual effect, so i put a sleep(1). thanks for ur intervention

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](http://osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/documentation/tutorial/collectives.php#barrier). There is a way to block processes from further action when they reach some point of computation until all other processes reach the same point.
Hope, it'll be something helpful. Your code is likely to look like this:

```
if (rank == 0)
{
    int all = nTasks-1; //wich is the number of processes -1

    while (all > 0)
    {
         Communicator.world.Receive<Pixelator>(Communicator.anySource, 1, out pixelus);
         if (pixelus.x == -1)
         {
             all--;
         }
    }
}
else
{                    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Communicator.world.Send<Pixelator>(some_data, 0, 1);
        //Here's the barrier
        Communicator.Barrier();
    }                    
    Communicator.world.Send<Pixelator>(-1, 0, 1);
}
```

It will definitely provide something like your output. But if barriers don't suit, I have no other guesses than give more work to processes so that they will have less time to communicate each other.